# This story was invalidated because: The object at app_url doesn't have a title

Tags: facebook-graph-api, invalidation

From the last two days, my Facebook application showed some weird text like on my application's usage story feeds:

> This story was invalidated because: The object at http://apps.facebook.com/socialrecruit/ doesn't have a title

What is the reason?

Comment: Same issue here, i am seeing this on 3 apps that are non game.
http://apps.facebook.com/shawnsspace
http://apps.facebook.com/anotherfeed
as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution. Change the head tag to

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

and add following meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="other">
<meta property="og:title" content="Social Recruit">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://apps.facebook.com/socialrecruit/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://thesocialrecruit.com/fb/images/main_app_image.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Social Recruit">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID">
```

You might need to wait for couple of hours for the changes take place.

Comment: this solution did not work for me, i am seeing the error in 3 different applications all of which are non games... The game apps seem to be working fine.

Comment: Same problem, we will try your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by removing an extra tag I had on my HTML file.
The extra tag was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

The HTML header I now have is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This did the trick for me, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved just by adding a title tag in the `head` section:

```
<head>
   ...
   <title> 
        My App Title
   </title>
   ...
</head>
```

That's it... I hope this helps.